# How to execute .sh file to start process in Monit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, sh, monit

So I have `puma_start_staging.sh` file. If I execute that file from terminal

`. /home/deploy/puma_start_staging.sh`

everything is ok. But monit can't execute that file.
Here's my config:

```
check process puma_staging with pidfile /home/deploy/apps/staging/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid
start program = "/bin/bash -c '. /home/deploy/puma_start_staging.sh'"
stop  program = "/bin/bash -c 'kill `cat /home/deploy/apps/staging/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid`'"
```

I get this in monit.log

```
[EEST Aug  4 10:56:10] info     : 'puma_staging' start: /bin/bash
[EEST Aug  4 10:56:40] error    : 'puma_staging' failed to start
[EEST Aug  4 10:56:40] info     : 'puma_staging' start action done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `. /home/deploy/...` is not executing anything; it is just sourcing, which is not the same.

Comment: @fedorqui if I put dot before it execute script but this works only in terminal

Comment: What I mean is this: [What is the difference between executing a bash script and sourcing a bash script?](http://superuser.com/q/176783/204979)